# how to implement basic authentication with spring security using keycloak

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

i want to use Keycloak as a authentication provider.
i do not want to use keycloak dependencies directly into my app. instead i want to use spring-security and webflux to access keycloak.

is there a way to implement basic authentication using spring security and keycloak. i know SecurityWebFilterChain class and @EnableWebFluxSecurity but how to integrate it with keycloak?

```
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated()).oauth2Login();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: basic authentication and oauth2 authentication are 2 different things. You question is ambiguous voted to close for not being clear enough of what it is you want.

Comment: i want to use keycloack with spring security and in keycloak i have enabled basic auth but i am not sure how to configure spring security with basic auth from keycloak

Comment: please read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask there is 100s of ways of implementing what you are asking for. The question is too broad, if you wish to understand how to implement basic security i suggest you start out by reading the spring security reference documentation and understand what it is you are asking for. Try out their examples, then read up on how keycloak works. Then start writing your implementation. And if you get stuck you post your full code, with error message, steps to reproduce, and a small compilable example for us to take a look at and we will help

Comment: you are asking for basic auth and you post code that shows oauth2 dependencies, that makes no sense, you can start reading here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-basic